# Unable to login in crashlytics in android using plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have installed the Crashlytics plugin 1.3.0 in eclipse and ADT Dev Tools 
version 23.X.X.

I am able to see Crashlytics window with login panel in eclipse but not able to login and see the list of apps. It shows me Invalid Login while entering the invalid credentials but showing me the same login panel after entering the valid credentials without any error. Google dropeed the support for Eclipse Android, but have some dependancy on it.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I believe I answered over email as well, but we deprecated our support for Eclipse and recommend using Android Studio.

Comment: Hi Mike, Actually i need to use it in Appcelerator Apps. I would like to know if instead of using it through plugins can we have some API's methods with which we can acces the methods to report the crash.

Comment: Gotcha, yea, we don't have support for Titanium and we don't have a public API at this point. If that changes, will update here!

Comment: I have installed the Fabric plugin in Appcelerator and able to login now. Also  I am able to see the entries of the App in plugin where we did Crashlytics integration in native Android.